# php Short URL Echo()

Tags: php

I use this for Short URL but it not work

```
 <?php
define('LINK_URL','$siteurl."/".ereg_replace(" ", "-", $show_wallpaper["caturl"])."-".$show_wallpaper["categoryid"]."-"."1.htm"');

 ?>

<a href="<?php echo LINK_URL; ?>">
```

How to Fix?

Comment: Define "it not work". What happened? What are the variables set to? What gets output?

Comment: Hm.. can't tell from what you put. What went wrong?

Comment: Yes if define not work then what i use?

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the single quotes from the second parameter, like this:

```
define('LINK_URL',$siteurl."/".ereg_replace(" ", "-", $show_wallpaper["caturl"])."-".$show_wallpaper["categoryid"]."-"."1.htm");
```

Answer (score 2):

The output is most likely this:

```
<a href="'LINK_URL','$siteurl."/".ereg_replace(" ", "-", $show_wallpaper["caturl"])."-".$show_wallpaper["categoryid"]."-"."1.htm"">
```

Just remove the quotes, like:

```
define('LINK_URL', $siteurl."/".str_replace(" ", "-", $show_wallpaper["caturl"])."-".$show_wallpaper["categoryid"]."-1.htm");
```